# measure short distance android GPS

Tags: java, android, gps

I am trying to get the distance from a predetermined location set by the user, to the users current position. The problem is that the distance it returns is all over the place, and is very inaccurate. Also, `SkettiList.get(i).Lat` and `SkettiList.get(i).Lon` are the constant Longitude and Latitude of the position the user set, and `Lat` and `Lon` are the users current Latitude and Longitude positions.  Here is my 
code:

```
float[] results=new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(SkettiList.get(i).Lat, SkettiList.get(i).Lon,Lat,Lon, results);
Log.i("SKT: ",results[0]+"");
```

Comment: probably nothing wrong with this code, and your user location is the thing that's totally wonky. e.g. dysfunctional gps, no gps at all producing random numbers, etc...

Answer (score 1):

GPS is only going to be so so for short distances and if you are stationary will 
bounce around a little.

That said you should make sure you are using FINE

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    ...
 </manifest>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

On my applications I throw away anything that is not at least 10 meters different then the last
location received.

Comment: I was originally doing that.